# Debug my web application using ant

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, ant

I am currently developing an MVC Application using Java EE Technologies and Eclipse as an IDE. To run my server and deploy my application I am using ANT. I would like to know how can I debug my Java Code through the ant tool or eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following `jvmarg` options to your tomcat start command:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xdebug"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5000,server=y,suspend=n"/>
```

You will be able to attach the Eclipse debugger on port 5000, using the `Remote Java Application` debug category.

Comment: Is it easier to run it from Eclipse without using ant? What should I do for that? In ANT I had configured all my external Jars to be in WEB-CONTENT/WEB-INF/LIB, but I imagine that in order for being able to run it directly from Eclipse, I sould place this external libraries somewhere else.

Comment: @user1084509 I prefer to run everything from `ant` because this way you already have everything configured and you don't need to maintain ant and Eclipse in sync. You can add the `ant` view window to eclipse and just run your ant task from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from eclipse:

- [enable debug on tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing)
- create a new debug configuration in eclipse that connects to tomcat

[See here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) for details.

But it is not a good idea to use ant to start tomcat in development. Use Eclipse WTP to start your tomcat and deploy applications on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I mentioned before, Im using ANT to start apache. Do you know how can I enable debug mode in tomcat via my ant start command? My ant task looks as follows: <target name="tomcat7-start">
            <echo>Starting Tomcat</echo>
            <java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" fork="true"
                            classpathref="tomcat.class.path">
                    <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${server.dir}"/>
            </java>
    </target>

Comment: you'd have to add the debug configuration in your catalina.sh/bat

Comment: I would like to follow your advice of not using ANT. I already configured my server in Eclipse, the problem now is that when trying to run my application, it doesn't find any servlet. What should I do to compile my classes, build the proyect and start running it? The option Project - Build all is disabled

Comment: you have to configure the deployment assembly of the project. Look for a WTP tutorial to see how