# WAR file created using Ant script not debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jboss

I am currently developing an Web Application using struts and Eclipse and JBoss 5.0 .I am Using Ant to compile and build the war structure, The web application is running successfully in Jboss and eclipse. But when comes to debugging point of view, while I am putting breakpoints in eclipse, the debugger is stopping at that breakpoint ( it does'nt even showing a attach source in eclipse) . 
I would like to know how can I debug my Java Code through the ant tool and  eclipse.

I saw the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423795/debug-my-web-application-using-ant). but it doesnt helped me.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I've missed in the build.xml. We should provide **debug=true** attribute while compiling our source code in **Ant**.

```
 <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" debug="true" >
     <classpath refid="classpath"/>
 </javac>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with ANT. You need to start JBoss in Debug mode. There are tens of [articles](https://justinjohnson.org/java/configuring-remote-debugging-in-jboss-as-7-and-eclipse/) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse) describing how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!.. But I know how to start the server in debug mode.. And I did all the above stuff in Debug mode itself. Still it is not capturing the ant build class in eclipse-jboss debugging mode but it worked for me in Maven Builded War file.